# Angular 1/$interpolate - interpolate array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

I have this array `stateData.submenu` :

```
    [
      {
        "template": "<span translate>myContacts</span>",
        "sref": "contact.list"
      },
      {
        "template": "<span translate>myProjects</span>",
        "sref": "project.list"
      },
      {
        "template": "<span translate>myRecommendations</span>
          <span class=\"badge\">{{ notificationBadge }}</span>",
        "sref": "recommendation.list"
      }
    ]
```

I would like to interpolate all `template` properties with the service `$interpolate`
I can interpret a single property for example with :

`this.notificationBadge = this.$interpolate(stateData.submenu[2].template)(this)`

How can I loop and interpolate all the properties using ecmaScript 2015 or Lodash for example ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "interpolate all the properties"? What result do you expect?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash the result of 
`this.notificationBadge = this.$interpolate(stateData.submenu)(this)`
to know that `submenu` is a array

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the purpose? `$interpolate` compiles a string with markup into an interpolation function, it can't work with array. What template are you expecting as a result?